# Preventing theft of Bitcoin ATM

Tags: bitcoin-atm

I am considering buying a [Lamassu](http://lamassu.is) Bitcoin ATM machine.

The small machine is apparently "grab resistant". Does anyone know how the grab resistant mechanism works? Are there hooks on the back?

Comment: The page you linked to says "Internal steel vault is securely bolted to wall, stand, or countertop". Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's getting there, yes! A picture showing the bolting would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [website](https://lamassu.is/#specs):

> The machine will be smash and grab resistant. It is not meant for
>   unattended or outdoor use, but it will have thick metal mounting
>   plates, a dual locking system and an internal strong box for the cash.

According to this [site](http://bluenotetechblog.com/?s=lamassu):

> The outer casing is a custom steel case made in Portugal. There’s a
>   Protec cylinder lock holding it closed. Inside, there’s yet another
>   steel case and another Protec lock. The tablet that runs the software
>   has no open ports, and all outgoing connections are via https.

Answer (score 0):

For either machine securely attach them to the surface they are sitting on. Bolt to the counter in a manner that can not be disassembled without opening the machine. For flow mounted machines secure to a concrete floor with large anchor bolts into the floor.